# Composite Key and using Multiple Column Attributes in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a composite key using two fields when using code first to existing fields in a table in a db;

```
    [Key,Column("driverId", Order=0)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="driverid")]
    public override int ID { get; set; }

    [Key,Column("type", Order=1)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="typeid")]
    public int Type { get; set; }
```

Now when I try to run a new migration i get the following error;

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.
>   DriversToVehicle_Driver_Target_DriversToVehicle_Driver_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

The DriversToVehicle table is as follows;

```
public partial class DriversToVehicle
{
    [Column("id"), Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("driverid")]
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DriverID")]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }

    [Column("vehicleid")]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VehicleID")]
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

Extending this question, originally a single key on the ID, i.e.

```
    [Column("driverId")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="driverid")]
    public override int ID { get; set; }
```

Now moving forward, how will this effect the other entities linking to it (by this i mean code first in the classes)? will ef automatically sort this out? or do I now need to have both keys in other entities when linking to this class?

e.g. as before I would have had

```
public virtual Driver myDriver;
```

Obviously now instead of linking on the ID alone it needs to be linked with the Type as well.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT FOR ANSWER**

Ok, I extracted the Type out to a seperate class. The main issue is now How do i mark the foreign key as also being a composite key?

I have the following classes

```
    public partial class DriverType 
    {
        [Column("Id")]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "drivertypeid")]
        public override int ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "drivertype")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in the Driver I have the following (reduced for brevity);

```
public partial class Driver : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    [Key,Column("driverId", Order=0)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="driverid")]
    public override int ID { get; set; }

    [Key,Column("type", Order=1)]
    [ForeignKey("DriverType")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="drivertypeid")]
    public int DriverTypeId { get; set; }
    public DriverType DriverType { get; set; }
```

How do I then add it to the DriverToVehicle class please? So far I have

public partial class DriversToVehicle
    {
        [Column("id"), Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

```
    [Column("driverid", Order=0), ForeignKey("Driver")]
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }

    [Column("type", Order = 1), ForeignKey("Driver")] 
    public int DriverTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DriverTypeId")]
    public DriverType DriverType { get; set; }

}
```

This doesnt look right to me though?

Comment: I don't understand your first question, what is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: looks like you're trying to configure a class for ***junction*** (or ***join***) table? That is normally hidden. What you should configure is the entity classes  representing `Driver` and `Type`.

Comment: Hi sorry, I;ve been looking at this for a while now, i've updated question does this make more sense now?

Comment: @Hopeless what you see above is the driver class. I have the requirement to now change this to be a composite key. Where the driverid and the type (int) will be the joint key

Comment: I'm not very familiar with code-based configuration, you should however post the related class (I guess it is `DriversToVehicle`, ...) and what you've done to try mapping between them (so that someone else could help). Once you change the old key to the composite key, all involved relationships should be taken in consideration to update again.

Comment: @Hopeless Sorry I see your question now. I've updated the question to include the class. I suppose this is part of my second question, i.e. do I need to add a Type tofield and mark both this and the driverID field ad the FK? If so how?

Comment: yes looks like you need to add a property `Type` to the related class `DriversToVehicle` together with a foreign key id (such as `TypeID`) and use the `ForeignKeyAttribute` (do exactly as what you do with the `Driver` property).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Drivers` table's Primary Key is now `(DriverId, Type)`, you can no longer reference your drivers by `DriverId` alone - you must reference them by both `DriverId` and `Type`. Therefore, your `DriversToVehicle` table needs to look something like this:

```
public partial class DriversToVehicle
{
    [Column("id"), Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("driverid")]
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DriverID")]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }

    [Column("DriverType")]
    public int DriverType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("type")]
    public int DriverType { get; set; }

    [Column("vehicleid")]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VehicleID")]
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

However, as @hopeless states above, you may not need to model this join table if you correctly model your `Driver` and `Vehicle` types correctly.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Rich, Ok this is great I understand what ou are doing here, Do I not need to link them using a foreign key here? also is there a typo in your answer (not being picky I just want tog et it right lol). i.e. How does EF know which two fields map to the Vehicle class?